# why my post ajax is not working?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

What I doing is facebook request dialog and get the user ID from javascript then post to php code to insert the userid in my database, in my facebook request dialog part I can get the user ID and request ID, only the ajax post part is not working.

my javascript coding:

```
function newInvite(){
    FB.ui({ 
    method : 'apprequests',
    title: 'X-MATCH',
     message: 'Come join US now, having fun here',                      
},                      
    function(response){
        var receiverIDs;
        if (response.request)  {
        var receiverIDs = response.to;  // GET USER ID
        alert(receiverIDs);                           
        //I stuck from here
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",                                       
            url:"<?=$fbconfig['baseUrl']?>/ajax2.php",                                            
            data : {receiverIDs :receiverIDs},
            success: function(msg){
                alert(msg);
            },
            error: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
            }
        });
        }
    }               
);
}
```

my php code(file name is ajax2.php):

```
<?php       
include 'config/config.php';
include_once "index.php";  
$Currentdatetime = date("Y-m-d h:i:s" ,strtotime("now"));                       
$senderID = $_POST['receiverIDs'];
$explode = explode(',', $senderID);
for ($i=0; $i<count($explode);$i++){
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_invite VALUES('$userid','$explode[$i]','0','50','$Currentdatetime','0')");
}
?>
```

any solution ? thanks

Comment: did u try to see this in firebug console ?

Comment: in my firebug it shown " $ is not defined"

Comment: @user Are you adding jQuery into the page?

Comment: I did not add any jquery into my page

Comment: @Oscar, well thats your problem!  You are trying to use the jQuery framework with that $.ajax(), check out my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add jquery into the header:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Use that tag, and read the [Downloading jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) article to learn about CDN.  Martin is right that it is the best way for static content (such as jquery), but it is important to understand what you are doing and not just do it.

Try changing the URL to :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",                                       
        url: "<?=$fbconfig['baseUrl']?>/ajax2.php",                                             
        data : { receiverIDs :receiverIDs },
        success: function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        },
        error: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
        }
    });
```

You don't need 2 sets of quotes around it.

Comment: thanks for reply, I had edit my code, see on top what I changed, but still the same it's not working

Comment: thank andrew jackman, I get what you mean , I had added the jquery on my header , now it's work, really thank for help :D

Comment: @Andrew why would he have to "remember" ? `but make sure you remember to`. Hmm, please edit your post again so I can remove this downvote, too

Comment: @Martin while you are correct that CDNs are useful, it is not part of the question, and we don't know his situation, so it is not necessarily correct for him to rely on it.  You can (almost) always rely on a local file. Thank you for your attempt to make sure every answer is good :)  You should read [7 Reasons Not To Use A CDN](http://www.sitepoint.com/7-reasons-not-to-use-a-cdn/), and pay attention to points 4, 5 and 7, any of which could apply to the asker.  That being said, I do support (and use) CDN for jQuery and jQuery UI, and I think it is a very useful idea.